# Using lapply on multiple functions

Tags: r, lapply

`HierCluster` is the list of data frames.

I can get the info about one cluster like this:

```
tail(sort(colMeans(HierCluster[[i]])))
```

where *i* is an i-th element in the list.

I used lapply to get the info on all the clusters at once:

```
lapply(lapply(lapply(HierCluster, colMeans), sort), tail)
```

But using lapply 3 times seems rather cumbersome, is there a more practical way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make an anonymous function that combines the three:

```
lapply(HierCluster, function(x) tail(sort(colMeans(x))))
```