# lapply() output as a dataframe of multiple values with multiple functions - R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lapply

I have this summary dataframe (from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58496094/lapply-output-as-a-dataframe-of-multiple-functions-r/)):

```
lst <- lapply(1:ncol(mtcars), function(i){
  x <- mtcars[[i]]
  data.frame(
    Variable_name = colnames(mtcars)[[i]],
    sum_unique = NROW(unique(x)), 
    NA_count = sum(is.na(x)), 
    NA_percent = round(sum(is.na(x))/NROW(x),2))  
  })
do.call(rbind, lst)
```

Where I want to add the five highest and lowest values, for each column:

```
lst <- lapply(1:ncol(mtcars), function(i){
  x <- mtcars[[i]]
  data.frame(
    variable_name = colnames(mtcars)[[i]],
    distinct = NROW(unique(x)), 
    NA_count = sum(is.na(x)), 
    NA_percent = round(sum(is.na(x))/NROW(x),2),
    first_5 = paste0(sort(x, decreasing=TRUE)[1:5],";"),
    last_5 = paste0(sort(x)[1:5],";")
  )   
})
do.call(rbind, lst)
```

But it creates a new row for each `first_5` and `last_5` values. Why happens this? And how can I solve it?

Comment: Hi, could you be more precise on the output you want ? You want to add the five highest and lowest values for each column, what does that mean ? 10 more rows ; 5  highest value  rows and 5 lowest value rows ?

Comment: And you want the max values of in values of what ? mpg I would say ?

Comment: if you want the for 5 highest/lowest value on the same line, use the parameter `collapse=";"` as in : 
`paste0(sort(x)[1:5], collapse=";")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Because you have five number for one spot, `paste0` itself cannot do the job. One solution is add to `toString` like this:

```
lst <- lapply(1:ncol(mtcars), function(i){
  x <- mtcars[[i]]
  data.frame(
    variable_name = colnames(mtcars)[[i]],
    distinct = NROW(unique(x)), 
    NA_count = sum(is.na(x)), 
    NA_percent = round(sum(is.na(x))/NROW(x),2),
    first_5 = paste0(toString(sort(x, decreasing=TRUE)[1:5]),";"),
    last_5 = paste0(toString(sort(x)[1:5]),";")
  )   
})
do.call(rbind, lst)
```

Comment: It worked! But can you explain the process? I still don't understand why it doesn't work without toString().